# Excel = operator isn't working as expected with multiple tabs

Tags: excel, tabs, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an Excel-file with 2 tabs:

```
Tab1

ActorID | ActorName
--------------------
4321    | ActorName1
4322    | ActorName2
4323    | ActorName3
4324    | ActorName4
```

In the second tab I want to put in the name of the actor and see if it's in the array

So I used this formula: `=(Tab1!A1:A10="ActorName1")`, but I get `FALSE`. When I use the same formula in the first tab (`=(A1:A10="ActorName1")`) I get `TRUE`.

I don't understand why I get `FALSE` if the formula is used in another tab :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula works on the tab only if the name you are searching is the first.  You are trying to compare an array to a single item, Excel will only look at the first.

To search a range of names use MATCH(). To return TRUE/FALSE wrap it in ISNUMBER(), as MATCH will return a number if found or an error if not found.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("ActorName1",Tab1!A1:A10,0))
```

Comment: I used it because I need it for lookup with multiple variables like you see [here](http://www.exceltactics.com/vlookup-multiple-criteria-using-index-match/4/)

Comment: @MichaelDeBoey okay, but you can't use it alone, it needs to be wrapped in something like MATCH using Ctrl-Shift-Enter to make it an array formula.  Sounds like you have an X-Y problem.  You are asking only part of the question.  What I have stated answers what you have asked.  Please tell us what you have and what you want.  This formula will return true if the name is in the list and false if it is not.

Comment: OK I guess I just open a new thread and delete this one to explain my problem in a whole?

Comment: @MichaelDeBoey no, this answered the question. you mark it as correct and then ask a new question.

Comment: OK will do that :-)

Comment: I'm unable to create a new question for it :/